# DocuSign Prepoluate Tab value per Recipient

Tags: c#, tabs, docusignapi

Using the SOAP API is there any way to pre-populate a tag within an envelope when I have multiple recipients, with different values. An example would be; I have 2 recipients (or potentially more) and a single tag/tab (text) in the template. I want this tag to be pre-populated with the Recipients's name so that when they get it, recipient 1 will see his/her name on the document tag and recipient 2 will his/her name.

I have tried getting the templates tabs and creating new ones based in the already existing ones values (mainly positioning and types and such) i just changed the values and recipient ID and adding those tabs to a list. However whenever I change a tab's values/recipient ID the other ones in the list change. I finalize the process by turning the list into an array and setting the envelopes tab to the new array of tabs.

Here is the proccess:

```
    newEnvelope.Tabs = GetTabs(newEnvelope);

    private Tab[] GetTabs(Envelope envelope) {

     Tab[] exsitingTabs = envelope.Tabs;
     List<Tab> newTabs = new List<Tab>();

     foreach(Recipient r in envelope.Recipients) {
        Tab tab = exsitingTabs .ElementAt(14); // Just a custom text tag
        tab.RecipientID = r.ID;
        tab.Value = r.UserName;
        newTabs.Add(tab); //The older tab info gets replaced by the new tab info.
                          // all are still there, the old ones just have the same info
                          // as the latest added one
     }
     return newTabs.ToArray();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can definitely pre-populate tabs for multiple recipients through DocuSign.  Try setting different `TabLabel`s for your recipients, that might resolve the duplication issue.  The reason I think that might be the issue is because when TabLabels are the same then the fields will update with the same value, but if they are different then they won't.

From the [DocuSign SOAP API](http://www.docusign.com/p/APIGuide/APIGuide.htm#Introduction+Changes/Introduction.htm) guide:

```
"Making custom tab’s TabLabel the same will cause the all like fields to update when the user enters data."
```

So in your for loop just try this:

```
foreach(Recipient r in envelope.Recipients) {
    Tab tab = newTabs.ElementAt(14); // Just a custom text tag
    tab.RecipientID = r.ID;
    tab.Value = r.UserName;

    tab.TabLabel = r.ID; // or some other unique value for each recipient

    newTabs.Add(tab); //The older tab info gets replaced by the new tab info.
                      // all are still there, the old ones just have the same info
                      // as the latest added one


 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the swift response. I have tried that and it seems it is still setting the old values with the latest ones. By the way I edited the old post, the new tab in the foreach loop should be

Comment: Tab tab = existingTabs.ElementAt(14);

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue you might be having is that DocuSign Tabs are per-recipient, that is they are assigned to a specific Recipient (or Recipient Role) in the Envelope.

For example, if you're sending a Loan Application and have "Signer 1" and "Signer 2", you would need to have a "Signer1Name" field to capture Signer 1's name, and "Signer2Name" for Signer 2 (although, the FullName field is auto-populated by DocuSign upon that recipient signing). You would not have a single "Name" Tab and then try to populate it with two different values (which is what your code appears to be doing).

Your code would might look something like what @Ergin wrote above:

```
List<Tab> tabList = new List<Tab>();
Recipient[] recipients = newEnvelope.Recipients;

foreach (Recipient r in recipients)
{
    Tab tab = new Tab();
    tab.RecipientID = r.ID;
    tab.TabLabel = string.Format("Recipient{0}Name", r.ID);
    tab.Value = r.UserName;
    tab.DocumentID = "1";

    tabList.Add(tab);
}

newEnvelope.Tabs = tabList.ToArray();
```

To get at the Name for Recipient #1, your tab label would be "Recipient1Name".